# remove value from two tables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two table is I remove the value in both tables if in a table of the value is marked by a flag to false

```
this.notInModel = function (tab1, tab2) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= tab1.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!tab1[i].inModel) {
            for (var j = 0; j <= tab2.length - 1; j++) {
                if(tab1[i].name === tab2[j].name)
                    tab2.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= tab2.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!tab2[i].inModel) {
            for (var j = 0; j <= tab1.length - 1; j++) {
                if(tab2[i].name === tab1[j].name)
                    tab1.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think my curls are a bit repetitive and wanted to know if we could not refactor the code ..?

thank you.

Comment: Why do you use `i = 1` and `j = 1` and not `i = 0` and `j = 0`?

Comment: @friedi i fixed my error ;)

Comment: alright. I updated my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.notInModel = function (tab1, tab2) {
    for (var i = tab1.length; i--; ) {
        for (var j = tab2.length; j--; ) {
            if(tab1[i].name !== tab2[j].name)
                continue;

            var tab2InModel = tab2[j].inModel;

            if(!tab1[i].inModel)
                tab2.splice(j, 1);

            if(!tab2InModel)
                tab1.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to loop through both tabs in reverse order and make the checks for the `name` and `inModel` properties for every element combination.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yman69mw/2/)**

Comment: @Mercer There was a tiny mistake in the loops. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it more modular by creating a new function to iterate through the arrays like this:

```
this.notInModel = function (tab1, tab2) {
  function nim(t1,t2) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= t1.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!t1[i].inModel) {
            for (var j = 1; j <= t2.length - 1; j++) {
                if(t1[i].name === t2[j].name)
                    t2.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
  }
  nim(tab1,tab2);
  nim(tab2,tab1);
}
```

Comment: @Rick_Hitchcock thx but the pb is wen i remove the value i need to remove in same time because if i remove in the tab1 after it's not remove in the tab2

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the problem.  My code should do the same as yours using vanilla JavaScript, but Angular may do something I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be equivalent, though I could not test without the definition of `splice` or without knowing how `inModel` field is set.

```
this.notInModel = function (tab1, tab2) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= tab1.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= tab2.length - 1; j++) {
            if(!tab1[i].inModel) {
                if (tab1[i].name === tab2[j].name)
                    tab2.splice(j, 1);
            }
            if(!tab2[j].inModel) {
                if (tab1[i].name === tab2[j].name)
                    tab1.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```